# ViewPagerIndicator not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

hi this is the first time for me to work with android viewPagerIndecator i got thee idea but the code missing sth I dont know how to show the title of the tabIndecator i just used the same code of online samle but no title shown  here's my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

         VAdapter vpadapter=new VAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
         ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
         vp.setAdapter(vadapter);

         TitlePageIndicator indicator =       (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(vp);
        indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }



         });



    }




}

class VAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public VPAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Fragment fragment = new ObjFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            // Our object is just an integer :-P
            args.putInt(ObjFragment.ARG_OBJECT, arg0 + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 5;
    }
}

class ObjFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
            // properly.
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.pager_fragment, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tx)).setText(
                Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
            return rootView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it was a problem with text color **^_^'**   it was white same as `background color`..

I just changd the color of the Background .